# JS Chrome Plugin - find text located in currently active tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

The code below is based on the samples provided in this example:
[StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16425582/how-to-create-chrome-extension-that-will-search-for-text-in-source-and-alter-for)

I am no good with JS but would like to adjust this code to highlight not just a number located in a  on the website, but rather highlight specific text located **anywhere** in the active tab, by either changing the font color or the highlighting the text. How can I do that?

Appreciate any help, I am new to JS and a little lost.
Thanks,
A2k

EDIT:
To clarify, I want to highlight the words Apple, Banana, etc. when they are located ANYWHERE in the active tab, not necessarily in a table or a td. This means the words can just as well be in a paragraph of text, in a label, an input field, etc.

highlightText.js

```
// keyword to highlight
var keywordArray = ["apple","banana","orange"];

keywordArray.forEach(function(v){
  var num = "(" + v + ")";

  // Select the '<td>' that contains the number we are looking for
  var td = $('td.col-question:contains('+num+')');

  // Make sure that this number exists
  if(td.length > 0){

    // Now that we have it we need to single out the number and replace it
    var span = td.html().replace(num,'<span class="highlight-num">'+num+'</span>');
    var n = td.html(span);
  }
    // Now instead of '(1000)' we have
    // '<span class="highlight-num">(1000)</span>'
    // We will color it in the css file
});
```

highlight.css

```
span.highlight-num{
  background-color: rgb(100, 255, 71);
}
```

Comment: `apple` and `banana` aren't numbers.

Comment: Does your text really contain strings like `(apple)` with `()` around the word you're looking for? Can you show examples of the HTML you're searching?

Comment: It doesn’t contain (), all I am looking for is the text “apple”, “banana” and so on. The text is located in various elements on the site such as labels, input fields, etc.

Comment: Then why do you add parentheses with `num = "(" + v + ")";`?

Comment: You already have parentheses around it in `$('td.col-question:contains('+num+')');` So that means it's searching for the parentheses literally.

Comment: You're searching for `:contains((apple))` instead of just `:contains(apple)`.

Comment: Again, this is from the sample, I do not have a table and no TD. All I want is to highlight the text located anywhere in the tab, not necessarily in a table.

Comment: In that question they're looking for numbers in parentheses, like `<td class="col-question">28 (510).`. That's why they added parentheses around the number. You need to change the code to match what you're doing differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is with:

```
var num = "(" + v + ")";
```

By doing this you are checking if the fruit `(apple)`, `(banana)` or `(orange)` is in your table. Instead, you can remove this to check whether `apple`, `banana` or `orange` is contained in your table.

You can instead use a regular expression to replace the keywords if they appear with spans around them to highlight them.

This does have its downsides however, as it won't work properly with text inputs as the markup will not be rendered as HTML.

See working example below:

```js
$(function() {
  const keywordArray = ["apple", "banana", "orange"];
  const body = $('body');

  body.html((_, innerHTML) =>
    innerHTML.replace(new RegExp(`(${keywordArray.join('|')})`, 'g'), '<span class="highlight-num">$1</span>')
  );
});
```

```css
span.highlight-num {
  background-color: rgb(100, 255, 71);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <p>The big apple is big</p>
  <em>The orange <strong>orange</strong> is orange</em>
  <br />
  <span>The green grape is green</span>
  <h4>The banana is a banana</h4>
</body>
```

Comment: How would that look if the text is not located in a table or td, but rather just text located in a label/input/text area/etc?

Comment: thank you very much, would love to buy you a beer. Cheers!

Comment: @Armitage2k no worries ;)